# Current in cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

Consider a cylindrical resistor. It is connected to battery and two points A and B are marked in as shown in figure:

[image: Cylindrical resistor]

The restistivity of cylinder increases linearly from A to B

If current at A and B is represented by IA and IB respectively then 
According to me as we move away from A resistance will increase , it will make resistance for charge to flow so the current decrease as we move away from the A  . I want to know am I correct ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I just want to know my approach is correct or not.

Comment: No "figure" in evidence.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WSIK9.jpg

Comment: Just apply Kirchhoff's current law or the law of conservation of charge.

Comment: Look at Ohms law. Is the voltage constant from A to any point through the resistor?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not correct.  In steady-state conditions, the current which enters the resistor at A will be the same as the current which leaves it at B.  How the resistivity varies between A and B is irrelevant.  I think this is the lesson which the problem teaches.

If this were not true then, as per @Farcher 's comment, charge would not be conserved.  It would accumulate or disappear somewhere between A and B.

Comment: What is the role of resistance here?

Comment: @user346279, the resistance will help you solve part "b" of the question, which will probably be something like "What's the equivalent resistance of the whole device?" or "What is the current through the device?".

Comment: I just want to know that resistance will not make any difference in flow of current.

Comment: @user346279 : It is not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking if the current going in at A is equal to the current coming out at B?  That is the question I have answered.  The resistance between A and B will determine **how much current** flows between A and B, but however much it is (0.1A, 10A, etc) the same amount will go in at A and come out at B.  If this does not answer your question, please could you make it clear what you are asking?

Comment: Let t=0 be an instant when current enter A, and t be an instant when current come out from B . Amount of cuurent that will be out at time instant t is equal to which enter at t=0 or it there will be some time lap for total current to come out

Comment: @user346279 : It seems to me that you really need to learn more about this topic by studying your textbook or online tutorials.  Physics SE is for specific questions, we don't provide tuition.

Comment: @user346279 : Current does not go in at A then come out from B after some time delay.  Current is like a river which is flowing all of the time around the circuit.